How to model two abstractions that have polymorphic relation in OOP
So I have a problem how to model data in my project. I have it in python and doing it in OOP fashion. But I cannot figure out a right way to model this case:
Let's say there is an abstract class called Fruit. Then there is a class that inherits from fruit that is named Apple and another one Grape.
Then I want to add to Fruit a parameter that is a list of another abstract class called Sauces. Then there is a class that inherits from sauce that is named Teriyaki. Teriyaki object should act differently when it is a sauce that is applied to apple and differently when it is applied to grape.
I want to call a function on each sauce in the list of sauces that would be somehow aware of post polimorphic type of fruit and apply adequate apply function.
Whatever design I come up with, it looks hacky and just ugly. Please help me with ideas or maybe there is a common pattern for it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Interesting challenge, here's my shot at it :)
file fruits.py (contains class hierarchy)
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import typing as tp
import operator
import re


class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, sauces: tp.List["Sauce"]):
        self.appearance = "{1} {0}".format((name := type(self).__name__.lower()),
                                           "an" if name.startswith(tuple("aeiou")) else "a")
        self.has_sauce = False
        num_sauces = len(sauces)
        for index, sauce in enumerate(sauces, start=1):
            sauce.apply_sauce(self, last_sauce=(index == num_sauces))

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.appearance


class Apple(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, sauces: tp.List["Sauce"]):
        super().__init__(sauces)
        # set apple-specific instance attributes here.


class Grape(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, sauces: tp.List["Sauce"]):
        super().__init__(sauces)
        # set grape-specific instance attributes here.


class Banana(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, sauces: tp.List["Sauce"]):
        super().__init__(sauces)
        # set banana-specific instance attributes here.


TupleOfFruits = tp.Tuple[tp.Type["Fruit"], ...]


class Sauce:
    def __init__(self):  # <- can modify to accept more parameters
        self.supported_fruits: TupleOfFruits = (Apple, Grape, Banana)  # can override in subclasses if needed
        self.sauce_name = " ".join(map(operator.methodcaller("lower"),
                                       re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z][^A-Z]*", type(self).__name__)))
        self.parent_fruit: tp.Optional[Fruit] = None

    def apply_sauce(self, fruit_obj: Fruit, last_sauce: bool = False) -> None:
        self.parent_fruit = fruit_obj
        self.check_fruit_supported()  # possibly won't return
        self.update_fruit_appearance(last_sauce)  # updates appearance of parent fruit
        if isinstance(self.parent_fruit, Apple):
            # do stuff specific to apples here
            pass
        elif isinstance(self.parent_fruit, Grape):
            # do stuff specific to grapes here
            pass

    def check_fruit_supported(self) -> None:
        if type(self.parent_fruit) not in self.supported_fruits:
            err_msg = "{}s really don't go with '{}'".format(type(self.parent_fruit).__name__.lower(),
                                                             self.sauce_name)
            raise TypeError(err_msg)

    def update_fruit_appearance(self, last_sauce: bool) -> None:
        if self.parent_fruit.has_sauce:
            if last_sauce:
                self.parent_fruit.appearance += "and '{}'".format(self.sauce_name)
            else:
                self.parent_fruit.appearance += "'{}', ".format(self.sauce_name)
        else:
            self.parent_fruit.appearance += " doused in '{}'{}".format(self.sauce_name, "" if last_sauce else ", ")
            self.parent_fruit.has_sauce = True

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.sauce_name


class Teriyaki(Sauce):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # modify supported fruits here with `self.supported_fruits = (...)`,
        # or set teriyaki-specific instance attributes


class MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApples(Sauce):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.supported_fruits: TupleOfFruits = (Apple,)


class MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApplesAndGrapes(Sauce):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.supported_fruits: TupleOfFruits = (Apple, Grape)


class Gravy(Sauce):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.supported_fruits: TupleOfFruits = ()  # eww


FruitT1 = tp.TypeVar("FruitT1", bound=Fruit)


def fruit_helper(fruit: tp.Type[FruitT1], sauces: tp.List[Sauce]) -> tp.Union[FruitT1, str]:
    """Attempts to construct an instance of `fruit` class with `sauces` passed to it. Returns constructed instance on
    success or exception message string on fail."""
    try:
        return fruit(sauces)
    except TypeError as err:
        return "error: {}".format(err)


def demo() -> None:
    # Just a demonstration
    print(fruit_helper(Banana, [MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApples()]))
    print(fruit_helper(Banana, [Teriyaki()]))
    print(fruit_helper(Apple, [Teriyaki(), MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApples(),
                               MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApplesAndGrapes()]))
    print(fruit_helper(Banana, [MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApplesAndGrapes()]))
    print(fruit_helper(Grape, [Teriyaki(), Gravy()]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()

file tests.py (contains unit tests)
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import collections.abc
import typing as tp
import itertools
import operator
import unittest
import shutil
import fruits
TEST_REPETITIONS = True


class TestSauces(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sauce_reprs(self) -> None:
        self.assertEqual(repr(fruits.Teriyaki()), "teriyaki")
        self.assertEqual(repr(fruits.MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApples()),
                         "mystery sauce that only goes with apples")
        self.assertEqual(repr(fruits.MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApplesAndGrapes()),
                         "mystery sauce that only goes with apples and grapes")
        self.assertEqual(repr(fruits.Gravy()), "gravy")


class TestFruits(unittest.TestCase):
    fruit_sauce_matches: tp.Dict[tp.Type[fruits.Fruit], tp.Tuple[tp.Type[fruits.Sauce], ...]] = \
        {fruits.Apple: (fruits.Teriyaki, fruits.MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApples,
                        fruits.MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApplesAndGrapes),
         fruits.Grape: (fruits.Teriyaki, fruits.MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApplesAndGrapes),
         fruits.Banana: (fruits.Teriyaki,)}
    all_fruits: tp.Tuple[tp.Type[fruits.Fruit], ...] = (fruits.Apple, fruits.Grape, fruits.Banana)
    all_sauces: tp.Tuple[tp.Type[fruits.Sauce], ...] = (fruits.Teriyaki, fruits.MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApples,
                                                        fruits.MysterySauceThatOnlyGoesWithApplesAndGrapes,
                                                        fruits.Gravy)

    def test_plain_fruit_appearance(self) -> None:
        self.assertEqual(repr(fruits.Apple([])), "an apple")
        self.assertEqual(repr(fruits.Grape([])), "a grape")
        self.assertEqual(repr(fruits.Banana([])), "a banana")

    def test_fruits_apply_single_sauce(self) -> None:
        print()
        fruit_sauce: collections.abc.Iterator[tp.Tuple[tp.Type[fruits.Fruit], tp.Type[fruits.Sauce]]] = \
            itertools.product(self.all_fruits, self.all_sauces)
        for fruit, sauce in fruit_sauce:
            if sauce in self.fruit_sauce_matches[fruit]:
                # `repr(fruit([]))` gets plain fruit appearance, `repr(sauce())` gets sauce appearance.
                expected = "{!r} doused in '{!r}'".format(fruit([]), sauce())
                print("testing: `assertEqual(repr(fruits.{.__name__}([fruits.{.__name__}()])), {!r})`"
                      .format(fruit, sauce, expected))
                self.assertEqual(repr(fruit([sauce()])), expected)
            else:
                print("testing: `assertRaises(TypeError, {.__name__}, [{.__name__}()])`".format(fruit, sauce))
                self.assertRaises(TypeError, fruit, [sauce()])

    def test_fruits_apply_mul_sauces(self) -> None:
        print()
        separator = "-" * shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
        for i in range(2, len(self.all_sauces) + 1):
            print(separator, "testing applying {} sauces...".format(i), sep="\n")
            self.apply_multiple_sauces(num_sauce=i)

    def apply_multiple_sauces(self, num_sauce: int = 2) -> None:
        if num_sauce < 2:
            err_msg = "`num_sauce` cannot be smaller than 2"
            raise ValueError(err_msg)
        pairs: collections.abc.Iterator[tp.Tuple[tp.Type[fruits.Fruit], tp.Tuple[tp.Type[fruits.Sauce], ...]]] = \
            itertools.product(self.all_fruits,
                              itertools.product(self.all_sauces, repeat=num_sauce) if TEST_REPETITIONS
                              else itertools.permutations(self.all_sauces, r=num_sauce))
        # Change module level constant `TEST_REPETITIONS` to `False` if you don't want to test applying the same sauce
        # more than once on the same fruit.
        for fruit, sauces in pairs:
            if all(map(operator.contains, itertools.repeat(self.fruit_sauce_matches[fruit]), sauces)):
                # All sauces are allowed for this fruit
                expected = "{!r} doused in {}" \
                           .format(fruit([]), ", ".join("'{!r}'".format(sauce()) if index < len(sauces)
                                                        else "and '{!r}'".format(sauce())
                                                        for index, sauce in enumerate(sauces, start=1)))
                print("testing: `assertEqual(repr({.__name__}([{}])), {!r})`"
                      .format(fruit, "(), ".join(map(operator.attrgetter("__name__"), sauces)) + "()", expected))
                self.assertEqual(repr(fruit([cls() for cls in sauces])), expected)
            else:
                # `sauces` contains a sauce that doesn't support current fruit
                print("testing: `assertRaises(TypeError, {.__name__}, [{}])`"
                      .format(fruit, "(), ".join(map(operator.attrgetter("__name__"), sauces)) + "()"))
                self.assertRaises(TypeError, fruit, [cls() for cls in sauces])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

Run fruits.py to see the demo output, and run tests.py (or python3 -m unittest -v tests.py) to run the unit tests. They all pass at the moment. And as the tests automatically calculates the combinations to test, they should continue to work if you add more fruits and sauces without making big changes to the code logic, as long as you update the fruit_sauce_matches, all_fruits, and all_sauces class variables in tests.TestFruits.
Not sure if this implementation is exactly what you want, but hopefully it will give you some ideas even if it isn't. There are some comments in the code to explain things. I might add more if I have time. This implementation mainly takes advantage of the fact that you can pass self to other classes, and then the other class can use the isinstance() function to check whether it accepts the type of that class object.
